# Only Allah can give life and take life

Tags: allah, miracles

Why did Allah give Isa (AS) the power to bring the dead back to life. We have been told only Allah has that power so doesn't this go against that? Also we only die once in the dunya but those who came back to life through the miracle then they had two lives? They had a second chance after they died?

Comment: **<comments deleted>** Comments are intended for constructive criticism and seeking clarification; they are not intended for answering questions (that's what "Post Your Answer" is for) and especially not for holding tangential conversations (you can use [chat] for that).

Answer (score 1):

Assalaamu alaikum warehmatullahi wabarakatuhu

Allah the Almighty has divine ways and signs that he wants to make others believe, various signs and miracles were shown during the time of Isa (A.S) and during Prophet Muhammed it (faith, belief) was in the form of divine inspirations, revelations, verses and also hadiths. There are many million ways Allah wants to create the faith in others of course it is also to show how great indeed and powerful Allah is, and he is able to do everything. ( "wa hua 'ala kulli shai in khadeer"). Also Isa (A.S) could only bring those to life whom Allah had willed, if Isa (A.S) would try to bring to life other than on those whom Allah willed, it would not happen.
"And certainly We sent apostles before you and gave them wives and children, and it is not in (the power of) an apostle to bring a sign except by Allah's permission; for every term there is an appointment." (13:38)

And you concerning why Allah subhaana wa Ta'ala did not simply through some of his creation in hell and some in heaven is that, for example: Your memory starts with the teacher making you stand on one foot or making you sit like a chicken. Your vision comes to this point only, you have no idea why, where, when or how you started to be in this position. You ask your teacher why? But they would say you know better because you used to do such things and behave like this in class.

So when on the day of judgement when you will be punished. One will ask the keepers of gate 'for what reason am I kept here? I do not remember of what bad I did? I did not get a chance to earn some good, give me another chance! So Allah Ta'ala made this whole process of birth till death to make us understand, know our surroundings and realtionships/bonds, family, why we came into existance, experience, growing up, overcoming obstacles, hardwork. All these feelings, emotions, practicality can not be simply shown to you. But when you will be asked on the day of judgement you will simply deny it! So it is also as a witness and that you know what you have already done an the opportunity you got, chances you lost! Allah's mercy on you his blessings and trials.

And specially for the evil-doers who make mistakes Allah gives them opportunity to repent and become better believers. This topic is very deep than you can actually converse on. You should know in differenciation of watching and actually doing it, praticality is more suited.
And Allah Ta'ala knows the best!!

Comment: But we didn't come into existence to be tested. We came into existence to worship Allah. That is what Allah tells us is our purpose. Also I understand that Isa (AS) could only perform the miracles by Allah's will but what I am saying is that Allah could have made something supernatural happen without the use of a human. For example we tell Christians that why would God need to teach humans by coming down in human form. Of course if God wanted to teach us he would not compare himself to us. Therefore Jesus cannot be God.

Comment: Yes, indeed we exist to worship and improve in our worship and adequates/manner, behaviour.

Comment: And about Allah's direct miracle I have an example:- An owner of a company knows how the company runs, he knows accounting, finances, management etc. but he appoints professions to do these for him. Why does he do that?? Because he has that position he has that respect, why would such a great, high level man do such jobs when he can appoint. He has a status, like superstars, footballers etc they have status, respect. Thus Allah is your Lord, he is above all!! He is Al- Jabbar, Al- Aleem, Al-A'laa, the Almighty, so he appointed his pure servants (angels, Prophets) to do the respective work.

Comment: But the accountant is actually doing the work and so the owner is not doing that task. However with the Miracle it is still Allah performing the miracle and Isa (AS) just kind of like acting it out in a way. It also makes people think that Jesus is actually bringing the dead to life which is why some though Jesus is God himself.

Comment: Yes those whose faith were only but little believed him to be a god, and those were astray. But those who have faith in Allah praise him and thank him for the miracles he shows to bring faith and blessings to his slaves.

Answer (score 1):

1. First of all 'Isa (peace be upon him) could do this miracles because of a permission of Allah as it's clearly stated in the Qur'an (for example ([3:49](http://legacy.quran.com/3/49)) and ([5:110](http://legacy.quran.com/5/110))), so it doesn't go against the power of Allah at all.
2. According to this [Fatwa](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/120549) their have been only 4 people whom have been brought back to life which are also mentioned in [tafsir al-Qurtobi](http://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?flag=1&bk_no=48&surano=3&ayano=49) and in the tafsir of [Fkhar-addyn ar-Razi](http://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?idfrom=1372&idto=1372&bk_no=132&ID=366) based on a narration on the authority of ibn 'Abbass(). One 'Azir or 'Adhir العاذر whom was a former friend of 'Isa, one was the son of an old (woman?) ابن العجوز, and the daughter of a man who used to take the tenth (Tithe) ابنة العاشر and Sam ibn Noh (peace be upon him) سام بن نوح  . But if i understood this story well Sam asked to return to death, while the others lead their (new) lives and had children afterwards. But this story has no sanad to our Messenger (peace be upon him).
3. It is apparently not recorded why they have given back life or whether this really was a second chance as far as i can tell!

And Allah knows best

Comment: But still they had two chances where as we only have one.

Answer (score -1):

God gave that ability to one of the greatest man on the world to demonstrate who is god and who is massenger. In quaran said when god create Adam teach him kalamah. All secrets that even angels dont know. God give any ability to his massengers to demonstrate his power and illustrated what is god'ability and what is sehr or magic. God bless you.